# Navigation Hover Over Background Image

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello I am trying to change the background image of my navigation buttons when I hover over it. When I hover over it at the moment it goes from orange to a light grey colour and the text stays white. I would like it to go to a white background colour #ffffff and text to be #F6861F

I have attached my template.css file below

I am using the protostar template. Please help me find where I need to change.

My website is,

Comment: will you please write part of code you are facing problem with

Comment: Hi Endô! Since some time, Joomla has its own StackExchange site: [joomla.stackexchange.com](http://joomla.stackexchange.com). I recommend you asking your future [tag:joomla]-related questions there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS code your looking for is on line 2843-2847

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

The new CSS you will need is as follows:

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F6861F;
}
```

Make those changes and you should bet all set.

Comment: Not a problem, happy I could help!